# 'urlname' is not a valid value for a primary key

Tags: python, django

I have looked to all questions asked in SO about this issue but no one seems to be appropriate to my case.

I have a search form containing a field of a foreign key. this is the model :

```
class A(models.Model):
    sa_datetime = models.DateTimeField(help_text='Start Date & Time')
    b= models.ForeignKey('B', help_text='B')

 class B(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(help_text='Start Date & Time')
    url= models.CharField(help_text='url', max_length=50)
```

and this is the search form :

```
 class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    start_datetime = forms.DateField(
      label=_("Start Date"),
      required=False,
      widget=customDateInput() )

    url= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
      label=_("URL"),
      required=False,
   queryset=B.objects.filter(url__isnull=False).values_list('url',flat=True),
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
        attrs={
            "class": "selectpicker form-control",
            "data-live-search": "true"
              }
          )
       )
```

and this my `view` :

```
class ASearchView(SearchView):

    template_name = "aa/aa_list.html"
    model = A
    form_class = SearchForm
    foreignFields = ["b"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_datetime = self.request.GET.get('start_datetime')
        url = self.request.GET.get('url')
        res= A.objects.select_related("b")
        if url:
           print 'heeeeeeeeeeeeereeeeee'
           res= res.filter(b__url=url)

        return res
```

I use a generic search form in my template , I just have to set the variables :

```
 {% with 'A_list' as model_index_url %}
       {% with 'B_search_view' as model_search_url %}
            {% with item_count=paginator.count app_name='name_app' model_name='A' %}
                 {% include 'name_app/search_form_wrapper.html' %}
            {% endwith %}
         {% endwith %}
 {% endwith %}
```

the values of `url` are displayed properly in the multiple select field ,but I inspected the code and I have figured out the problem. it was due to the `value` of the selected option was the name of the url , and it must be the id of the foreign key so that it could be matched to the foreign key object.

I don't know how to correct this , I don't want to create a new search form for this case . and I don't want to change `__str__` function to retun `url` name.

Is this possible or I should write a custom form for this case ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how that could happen as `res= res.filter(b__url=url)` would filter on `url` field and not id.

Comment: I think the view is not invoked when submitiing the search form .. The print message just before it  is not shown in console :/